# Pointing out city from map image of world with longitude and latitude

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a map image 800px wide.

How can I figure out a city?

like New York has 40.75 latitude and -73.98 longitude. I have to pin a mark over this point.

Before I have done with x_axis and y_axis which gives problem on more cities figure because i manually had to input values.
now i have database with all cities with latitude and longitude.
or is there any way that i can convert latitude and longitude to x and y axis.

```
x = image.width * (longitude + 180) / (2 * 180)
y = image.height * (latitude + 180) / (2 * 180)
```

Answer (score 2):

The maths is pretty easy if you want to do it by hand(or in the database) but you will probably be best served by setting up a desktop GIS to draw the output image once or if you need interactivity then a web map server will be a better way to go.